# Remove data file in FS module Emscripten

Tags: emscripten

How to correctly remove data file in emscripten's FS? 
Currently i'm using:

```
FS.truncate(..);
FS.unlink(..);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlink usually sufficient, memory will be freed without truncate before, if there is no other links to this file.